# Bad IL format in Unicorn

Tags: unicorn

Unicorn 3.2
Sitecore 8.2 160729

When I sync, it crashes with this error. But only on a few projects.

```
[A] master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Navigation/_Navigable/Navigation/LinkTitle (230de8d4-f378-40b0-9c46-c1cfb5facf98)
    ERROR: Bad IL format. (System.BadImageFormatException)
    at Sitecore.Data.Database.GetItem(ID itemId) 
    at Unicorn.Pipelines.UnicornSyncComplete.SyncedItemPostProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__1(ChangeEntry change) 
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() 
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() 
    at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) 
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
    at Unicorn.Pipelines.UnicornSyncComplete.SyncedItemPostProcessor.Process(UnicornSyncCompletePipelineArgs args) 
    at (Object , Object[] ) 
    at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) 
    at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) 
    at Unicorn.SerializationHelper.SyncTree(IConfiguration configuration, Action`1 rootLoadedCallback, IItemData[] roots) 
    at Unicorn.ControlPanel.Pipelines.UnicornControlPanelRequest.SyncVerb.Process(IProgressStatus progress, ILogger additionalLogger)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unicorn 3.2 is built against .NET 4.5, and Sitecore 8.2 is built against .NET 4.5.2. There are some funny edge cases where the earlier framework assembly calling the later framework assembly breaks - like this one.

To fix this update to Unicorn 3.3 RC9, which is built against .NET 4.5.2 and squashes a bunch of bugs. It's a plain ol' NuGet package upgrade to install it. Refer to https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn/issues/175

Comment: You've got the answer from the Father of Unicorn :)